# Max reduce in CUDA Fortran

Tags: cuda, fortran, reduction

I am trying to perform reduction in CUDA Fortran; what I did so far is something like that, performing the reduction in two steps (see the CUDA kernels below).

In the first kernel I am doing some simple computation and I declare a shared array for a block of threads to store the value of `abs(a - anew)`; once the threads are synchronized, I compute the max value of this shared array, that I store in an intermediate array of dimension `gridDim%x * gridDim%y`.

In the second kernel, I am reading this array (in a single block of threads) and try to compute the max value of it.

Here is the whole code:

```
module commons
   integer, parameter :: dp=kind(1.d0)
   integer, parameter :: nx=1024, ny=1024
   integer, parameter :: block_dimx=16, block_dimy=32
end module commons

module kernels
  use commons
contains
  attributes(global) subroutine kernel_gpu_reduce(a, anew, error, nxi, nyi)
    implicit none

    integer, value, intent(in) :: nxi, nyi
    real(dp), dimension(nxi,nyi), intent(in) :: a
    real(dp), dimension(nxi,nyi), intent(inout) :: anew
    real(dp), dimension(nxi/block_dimx+1,nyi/block_dimy+1), intent(inout) :: error
    real(dp), shared, dimension(block_dimx,block_dimy) :: err_sh
    integer :: i, j, k, tx, ty

    i = (blockIdx%x - 1)*blockDim%x + threadIdx%x
    j = (blockIdx%y - 1)*blockDim%y + threadIdx%y
    tx = threadIdx%x
    ty = threadIdx%y

    if (i > 1 .and. i < nxi .and. j > 1 .and. j < nyi) then
       anew(i,j) = 0.25d0*(a(i-1,j) + a(i+1,j) &
                       & + a(i,j-1) + a(i,j+1))
       err_sh(tx,ty) = abs(anew(i,j) - a(i,j))
    endif
    call syncthreads()

    error(blockIdx%x,blockIdx%y) = maxval(err_sh)

  end subroutine kernel_gpu_reduce

  attributes(global) subroutine max_reduce(local_error, error, nxi, nyi)
    implicit none

    integer, value, intent(in) :: nxi, nyi
    real(dp), dimension(nxi,nyi), intent(in) :: local_error
    real(dp), intent(out) :: error
    real(dp), shared, dimension(nxi) :: shared_error
    integer :: tx, i

    tx = threadIdx%x

    shared_error(tx) = 0.d0
    if (tx >=1 .and. tx <= nxi) shared_error(tx) = maxval(local_error(tx,:))
    call syncthreads()

    error = maxval(shared_error)

  end subroutine max_reduce
end module kernels

program laplace
  use cudafor
  use kernels
  use commons
  implicit none

  real(dp), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: a, anew
  real(dp) :: error=1.d0
  real(dp), device, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: adev, adevnew
  real(dp), device, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: edev
  real(dp), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: ehost
  real(dp), device :: error_dev
  integer    :: i
  integer    :: num_device, h_status, ierrSync, ierrAsync
  type(dim3) :: dimGrid, dimBlock

  num_device = 0
  h_status   = cudaSetDevice(num_device)

  dimGrid  = dim3(nx/block_dimx+1, ny/block_dimy+1, 1)
  dimBlock = dim3(block_dimx, block_dimy, 1)

  allocate(a(nx,ny), anew(nx,ny))
  allocate(adev(nx,ny), adevnew(nx,ny))
  allocate(edev(dimGrid%x,dimGrid%y), ehost(dimGrid%x,dimGrid%y))

  do i = 1, nx
     a(i,:) = 1.d0
     anew(i,:) = 1.d0
  enddo

  adev    = a
  adevnew = anew

  call kernel_gpu_reduce<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(adev, adevnew, edev, nx, ny)

  ierrSync = cudaGetLastError()
  ierrAsync = cudaDeviceSynchronize()
  if (ierrSync /= cudaSuccess) write(*,*) &
     & 'Sync kernel error - 1st kernel:', cudaGetErrorString(ierrSync)
  if (ierrAsync /= cudaSuccess) write(*,*) &
     & 'Async kernel error - 1st kernel:', cudaGetErrorString(ierrAsync)

  call max_reduce<<<1, dimGrid%x>>>(edev, error_dev, dimGrid%x, dimGrid%y)

  ierrSync = cudaGetLastError()
  ierrAsync = cudaDeviceSynchronize()
  if (ierrSync /= cudaSuccess) write(*,*) &
     & 'Sync kernel error - 2nd kernel:', cudaGetErrorString(ierrSync)
  if (ierrAsync /= cudaSuccess) write(*,*) &
     & 'Async kernel error - 2nd kernel:', cudaGetErrorString(ierrAsync)

  error = error_dev
  print*, 'error from kernel: ', error
  ehost = edev
  error = maxval(ehost)
  print*, 'error from host: ', error

  deallocate(a, anew, adev, adevnew, edev, ehost)

end program laplace
```

I first had a problem because of the kernel configuration of the second kernel (which was `<<<1, dimGrid>>>`); I modified the code following Robert's answer. Now I have a memory access error:

```
 Async kernel error - 2nd kernel:
 an illegal memory access was encountered                                                                                        
0: copyout Memcpy (host=0x666bf0, dev=0x4203e20000, size=8) FAILED: 77(an illegal memory access was encountered)
```

And, if I run it with `cuda-memcheck`:

```
========= Invalid __shared__ write of size 8
=========     at 0x00000060 in kernels_max_reduce_
=========     by thread (1,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x00000008 is out of bounds
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/libcuda.so (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2c5) [0x14ad95]
```

for every thread.

The code is compiled with PGI Fortran 14.9 and CUDA 6.5 on a Tesla K20 card (with CUDA capability 3.5). I compile it with:

```
pgfortran -Mcuda -ta:nvidia,cc35 laplace.f90 -o laplace
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do [proper cuda error checking in CUDA Fortran](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-query-device-properties-and-handle-errors-cuda-fortran/).  You should do so in your code.

One problem is that you're trying to launch too many threads (per block) in your second kernel:

```
call max_reduce<<<1, dimGrid>>>(edev, error_dev, dimGrid%x, dimGrid%y)
                     ^^^^^^^
```

The `dimGrid` parameter has previously been computed to be:

```
dimGrid  = dim3(nx/block_dimx+1, ny/block_dimy+1, 1);
```

Substituting actual values, we have:

```
dimGrid = dim3(1024/16 + 1, 1024/32 +1);
```

i.e.

```
dimGrid = dim3(65,33);
```

But you are not allowed to request 65*33 = 2145 threads per block.  The maximum is either 512 or 1024 depending on what device architecture target you are compiling for.

Because of this error, your second kernel is not running at all.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the error handling, I've just started with CUDA Fortran. I still have a problem though; I modify the call to `max_reduce` that looks like `call max_reduce<<<1, dimGrid%x>>>(...)` now, but I have a out-of-bounds memory error. I added checks on the thread index, but it still fails. Actually, even if I have only the initialization of `shared_error`, it fails even though the size of this shared array seems in accordance to the number of threads in the block. Any idea?

Comment: I tried to recompile the example with `-Mcuda=emu` and `-Mbounds` to check array bounds, but I did not help so far.

Comment: Your program has a number of strange characteristics to me.  For example, you don't seem to allocate either `a` or `anew` on the host.  And I don't know what the `commons` module is, either.  If you provide complete codes, including file names and compile command, and the version of PGI compilers you are using, I'll take a look.

Comment: I edited the code, I somehow lost the allocation of `a` and `anew` in the copy/paste of the code. `commons` module is defined just before the main program. It seems to me that everything needed to get it working is there now. I also did a test where I replaced the `do` loop in `max_reduce` by this line: `shared_error(tx) = maxval(local_error(tx,:))` (if it can be of any help). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The code you have posted still has the invalid kernel launch configuration.   And you have still chosen not to implement proper cuda error checking.  And you're still not initializing `a`.   How could 0.25 be the "correct value" if `a` is uninitialized?  I'd suggest putting a little more effort into getting it right if you want help.  I would also suggest that defining `nx` and `ny` in your commons module, and also using those same names as subroutine parameters is a bad idea, and confusing.

Comment: Sorry I did my edit too fast. I hope I forgot nothing this time. I am using PGI compiler version 14.9 and with the flags `-Mcuda -ta:nvidia,cc35`; for debugging, I replace these flags by `-Mcuda=emu -Mbounds -g -traceback`.

Comment: Your code still doesn't compile.  Is it really that difficult?  Rather than "hoping", why don't you do what I would have to do?  Start a new project, copy the code you have posted out of this question into it, and see if it compiles correctly.  If it does, report the exact output you get from the program.

Comment: For the code you have posted now, if you add the proper declaration in your program for the `i` variable, and change the shared definition in your `max_reduce` kernel to `real(dp), shared, dimension(128) :: shared_error` your program runs for me without error.  The actual error printout is zero for both cases - but this makes sense to me since you are initializing your `a` array all to the same value.  If you want to know what's going on with that shared variable definition, I suggest you post a new question.  Note that your shared definition in the first kernel  is working correctly.